# OnLongClick and expand - collapse doesn't work simultaneously with Expandable ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview

i have to popup alert dialog on long press of Group row in expandable listview .And it works when i implemented it in `onGroupView` method of my `BaseExpandableListAdapter` class.But after this expand collapse functionality is not working . What i think is long click event fetches the user interaction first and so it is hampering  group view to expand.

I have set `onLongClickListener` on inflated view of group .

However when i do same with childs.It works perfectly fine as childs in expandable list do not have basic functionality like groups (Expanding and Collapsing).

can any one suggest me how to intercept both events (long click + expand - collapse).

Answer (score 0):

You can setOnItemLongClickListener on your expandablelistview.
`ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP` is the if of a group, change it to 
`ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD` and you can manipulate with longclicks on group childs.

```
    pager_income = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.income_scroll);

    pager_income.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(id) == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(c, "Loong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                toast.show();

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```